# LibGDX Problems with render method ******FIXED*******

Tags: java, libgdx

```
 Attempt to read from field 'com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array com.rocketdefender.GameWorld.GameWorld.rockets' on a null object reference
```

I have been trying to render a array of rockets and update them so they move down the screen but it just comes up with this error when i run on mobile. There are no errors until I run the program. I have tried to fix but have no idea why the array is null in the first place.

```
public class GameWorld {

    public Array<Rocket> rockets;
    private long lastDropTime = 0;
    private Rocket rocket;
    private SpriteBatch batch;

    public GameWorld(){
        rockets = new Array<Rocket>();
    }

    public void update(float delta){

        Iterator<Rocket> iter = rockets.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            Rocket nextRocket = iter.next();
            nextRocket.y -= 200 * delta;
            if (nextRocket.y + 64 < 0) iter.remove();
        }
        if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnRocket();

    }

    public void spawnRocket(){
        rocket = new Rocket(20, 30);
        rockets.add(rocket);
        lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
    }
    ...
}
```

---

```
public Rocket(int width, int height) {
    rocket = new Rectangle();
    rocket.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800- (width * 2));
    rocket.y = 100;
    rocket.width = width;
    rocket.height = height;
}
```

---

GameRenderer Class

```
    public class GameRenderer {

    private GameWorld myWorld;

    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private SpriteBatch batch;

    private int GameHeight;

    public GameRenderer(GameWorld world, float GameHeight) {
        myWorld = world;
        this.GameHeight = (int) GameHeight;

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 136, 204);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    // Attach batch to camera
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
}


    public void render(){
        cam.update();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        for(Rocket nextRocket: myWorld.rockets) {
              batch.draw(AssetLoader.rocket, nextRocket.x, nextRocket.y);
        }
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: You've broken up the files so I don't know which line is listed in the stack trace - please could you mark GameRenderer.java line 46

Comment: I think AssetLoader.rocket is null, are you sure it is loaded?

Comment: @MattRandell The texture is loading but it says line 45 now for some reason

Comment: where do you initialize `myWorld` object?

Comment: Can you [edit] to include more of the `GameRenderer` class? Especially the fields and constructor?

Comment: where do you do the `myWorld = new GameWorld(...)`? include that part please.

Comment: It was a very poor mistake. I failed to initiliaze the variable. I think it was due to following a tutorial and assuming it was correct. Thank you for solving such a stupid mistake on my behalf.

Answer (score 0):

The anwser was that i simply failed to initiliaze a variable properly a mistake on my half.